# Foreign key constraints seem ignored by mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am just making a foreign key reference of parent table in a child table. When I try to delete the row from the parent table whose reference is there in child table, surprisingly it allows me to delete it. I have tried to create child table explicitly by writing on delete restrict and also without it, but to no help. Any ideas why this is happening? Below is the code I am using while creating the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE region
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE aggregator
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE gateway
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
region_id int ,
aggregator_id int ,
is_public boolean  DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES region(id),
FOREIGN KEY (aggregator_id) REFERENCES aggregator(id)
);
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a row in the child table that refers to just deleted parent row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both parent and child table need to be INNODB tables.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE region
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE aggregator
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE gateway
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
region_id int ,
aggregator_id int ,
is_public boolean  DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES region(id),
FOREIGN KEY (aggregator_id) REFERENCES aggregator(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Thanks dude it worked. By the way why do we need to write ENGINE=INNODB in all the create table queries? Why doesn't foreign key constraint work without it ? There has to be a backward compactibility  even if mysql is releasing something new

Comment: @vishnupratapsingh You could change the config to set default engine to INNODB too. And Why doesn't foreign key constraint work without it is because INNODB engine designed to support that.

Answer (score 0):

Do mean to say that if you delete parent table and child table deletes automatic? If yes then once go through cascading rules.

Comment: no What i mean to say is when a row of parent table has reference in a child table , then according to foreign key rules of referential integrity mysql should not allow me to delete that row from parent table but actually i'm able to delete that row from parent table without any error